# Which level of complexity of equations that Mathematica Solve or Reduce functions cannot deal with?

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

Here I have a system of equations which takes $B$ matrix as input, and output the solutions. The code works very well for 4-rows matrices $B$ that I tried, however it is hard to give solutions in finite time when $B$ is equal to the following matrix.

Why this happens? Is it because the dimensions of the corresponding equations are too high to be dealt with by `Solve (Reduce)`? which level of complexity of equations that Mathematica Solve or Reduce functions cannot deal with? Is it possible to write a scalable code   for this task?

```
B={{1,-1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1},{0,1,-1,0,0,0,1,-1,0,0},{-1,0,0,0,0,1,-1,0,-1,0},{0,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0,1,1},{0,0,0,1,-1,-1,0,1,0,0}};
```

```
vec = {a, b, c, d, 0};
trigs = B . Sin[Transpose[B] . vec];
polys = TrigExpand /@ trigs /. {Sin[a] -> sa, Sin[b] -> sb, 
   Sin[c] -> sc, Sin[d] -> sd, Cos[a] -> ca, Cos[b] -> cb, 
   Cos[c] -> cc, Cos[d] -> cd};
allfuns = 
 Join[polys, {sa^2 + ca^2 - 1, sb^2 + cb^2 - 1, sc^2 + cc^2 - 1, 
   sd^2 + cd^2 - 1}];
gb = GroebnerBasis[allfuns, {sa, sb, sc, sd}, {ca, cb, cc, cd}];
sol = Reduce[gb == 0] /. {sa -> Sin[a], sb -> Sin[b], sc -> Sin[c], 
   sd -> Sin[d], ca -> Cos[a], cb -> Cos[b], cc -> Cos[c], 
   cd -> Cos[d]};
oldeqns = And @@ Thread[trigs == 0];
neweqns = FullSimplify[oldeqns && sol];
Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a < 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b < 2 \[Pi] && 
   0 <= c < 2 Pi && 0 <= d < 2 Pi, {a, b, c, d}, 
  Reals] // FullSimplify
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

### **Update**

Here I give a try for the answer.

To look in detail of the Grobner basis produced in the code, I paste part of it due to its long length

```
{-1215 sd + 3888 sb^2 sd - 2592 sb^4 sd - 2304 sb^6 sd + 
  2304 sb^8 sd + 3888 sb sc sd - 5184 sb^3 sc sd - 6912 sb^5 sc sd + 
  9216 sb^7 sc sd + 3888 sc^2 sd - 7776 sb^2 sc^2 sd - 
  11520 sb^4 sc^2 sd + 16896 sb^6 sc^2 sd + 4096 sb^8 sc^2 sd - 
  5184 sb sc^3 sd - 11520 sb^3 sc^3 sd + 18432 sb^5 sc^3 sd + 
  16384 sb^7 sc^3 sd - 2592 sc^4 sd - 11520 sb^2 sc^4 sd + 
  19200 sb^4 sc^4 sd + 32768 sb^6 sc^4 sd - 6912 sb sc^5 sd + 
  18432 sb^3 sc^5 sd + 40960 sb^5 sc^5 sd - 2304 sc^6 sd + 
  16896 sb^2 sc^6 sd + 32768 sb^4 sc^6 sd + 9216 sb sc^7 sd + 
  16384 sb^3 sc^7 sd + 2304 sc^8 sd + 4096 sb^2 sc^8 sd + 
  3888 sb sd^2 - 5184 sb^3 sd^2 - 6912 sb^5 sd^2 + 9216 sb^7 sd^2 + 
  3888 sc sd^2 - 864 sb^2 sc sd^2 - 38016 sb^4 sc sd^2 + 
  32256 sb^6 sc sd^2 + 14336 sb^8 sc sd^2 - 864 sb sc^2 sd^2 - 
  64512 sb^3 sc^2 sd^2 + 50688 sb^5 sc^2 sd^2 + 
  73728 sb^7 sc^2 sd^2 - 5184 sc^3 sd^2 - 64512 sb^2 sc^3 sd^2 + 
  53760 sb^4 sc^3 sd^2 + 174080 sb^6 sc^3 sd^2 + 
  16384 sb^8 sc^3 sd^2 - 38016 sb sc^4 sd^2 + 53760 sb^3 sc^4 sd^2 + 
  247808 sb^5 sc^4 sd^2 + 65536 sb^7 sc^4 sd^2 - 6912 sc^5 sd^2 + 
  50688 sb^2 sc^5 sd^2 + 247808 sb^4 sc^5 sd^2 + 
  114688 sb^6 sc^5 sd^2 + 32256 sb sc^6 sd^2 + 
  174080 sb^3 sc^6 sd^2 + 114688 sb^5 sc^6 sd^2 + 9216 sc^7 sd^2 + 
  73728 sb^2 sc^7 sd^2 + 65536 sb^4 sc^7 sd^2 + 14336 sb sc^8 sd^2 + 
  16384 sb^3 sc^8 sd^2 + 3888 sd^3 - 7776 sb^2 sd^3 - 
  11520 sb^4 sd^3 + 16896 sb^6 sd^3 + 4096 sb^8 sd^3 ...
```

Nonetheless, it is already enough to see that the Grobner basis involves 8-degree terms, maybe this is the reason that Mathematica cannot find the solution. The [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory) asserts that

***a general polynomial of degree at least five cannot be solved by radicals***

That is to say, there is no general formula to compute the roots of polynomials of higher degree.

Comment: Rational roots of polynomials over the rationals of arbitrary degree are easily found.

Comment: @user64494 Does this has contradiction to Galois theory ?

Answer (score 2):

How to get at least a few solutions.

Reduce first for Sin of variables and then Solve for variables.

```
(B = {{1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 
 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0}}) // MatrixForm

vec = {a, b, c, d, 0};
(trigs = B.Sin[Transpose[B].vec]) // TableForm

trigs0 = Thread[TrigExpand[trigs] == 0];

condsinlist = {-1 <= Sin[a] <= 1, -1 <= Sin[b] <= 1, -1 <= Sin[c] <= 
1, -1 <= Sin[d] <= 1};

varslist = {a, b, c, d};

condvars = -Pi <= a <= Pi && -Pi <= b <= Pi && -Pi <= c <= 
Pi && -Pi <= d <= Pi;

redall0 = Reduce[Join[trigs0, condsinlist], Reals];

le0b = LogicalExpand[#] & /@ redall0;

TraditionalForm[
  le0b //. Or -> 
Composition[(Column[#, Right, Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, 
   Frame -> All] &), List]]

(tabb = Table[{TimeConstrained[
  Solve[le0b[[i]] && condvars, varslist, Reals, Method -> Reduce],
   3], "i =", i}, {i, 1, Length[le0b]}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

```
trigs0 /. DeleteCases[Flatten[tabb[[All, 1]], 1], $Aborted]

(*   True   *)
```

Examine the  $Aborted equations (aborted after 3 seconds) further to may be get more solutions.

Comment: I got the error ```Join::heads: Heads Equal and List at positions 1 and 2 are expected to be the same.  ``` ```Reduce::naqs: Join[B.Sin[Transpose[B].{a,b,c,d,0}]==0,{-1<=Sin[a]<=1,-1<=Sin[b]<=1,-1<=Sin[c]<=1,-1<=Sin[d]<=1}] is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.```

Comment: Seems you have not defined B. Start with a fresh Kenel (`Quit` ) and copy/paste my code. Works well in version 8.0

Comment: Thanks, it works. Does the code find all solutions or part of them?

Comment: As i wrote "Examine the $Aborted equations (aborted after 3 seconds) further to may be get more solutions."  May be you can get some more analytical/exact solutions. But i think, some can only be found numericaly.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your "and what kind of complexity of equations that Mathematica cannot solve?", here is an example of simple trig equation on   which `Reduce`, `Solve`, and `FindInstance` stuck:

```
FindInstance[Sin[x]*Sin[1755*x]*Sin[2011*x] == 1 && x > -Pi && x <= Pi, x, Reals]
```

The above equation  is solved by hand as follows. The equation `Sin[x]*Sin[1755*x]*Sin[2011*x] == 1` over the reals implies `Sin[x]==1` or `Sin[x]==-1`. It remains to test `x==Pi/2` and `x==-Pi/2`. Only the former satisfies the equation.

Comment: Can the down vote be explained? What is wrong in my answer? Deep regard.

Comment: BTW, the equation under consideration has complex roots too, e.g. $- 3.00144974730400- 0.000885659243711501 \,\mathrm{I}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, this example gets stuck as well. Could you explain more about why this happens? (I just noticed that the down vote is canceled, maybe someone click it by mistake: ) )

Comment: @Hi_dynamics: No, I can't explain it.

Comment: @user64494 , Reduce can do your equation  `Reduce[{s1 s2 s3 == 1, s1 == Sin[x], s2 == Sin[1755 x ], 
  s3 == Sin[2011 x], -Pi < x <= Pi, -1 <= s1 <= 1, -1 <= s2 <= 
   1, -1 <= s3 <= 1}, {x, s1, s2, s3}, Reals] `  yields `x == \[Pi]/2 && s1 == 1 && s2 == -1 && s3 == -1 `  (version 8.0)

Comment: @Akku14: No response from `Reduce[{s1 s2 s3 == 1, s1 == Sin[x^Catalan], s2 == Sin[1755 x^Catalan],
   s3 == Sin[2011 x^Catalan], -Pi < x <= Pi, -1 <= s1 <= 1, -1 <= s2 <=
    1, -1 <= s3 <= 1}, {x, s1, s2, s3}, Reals]` during a long time.

Comment: @user64494  , in version 8.0 result in 8 seconds  `{8.282, x == (\[Pi]/2)^(1/Catalan) && s1 == 1 && s2 == -1 && s3 == -1} `

Comment: @Akku14: No responce from `Reduce[{s1 s2 s3 == 1, s1 == Sin[x^Catalan], s2 == Sin[1755 x^Catalan],    s3 == Sin[2011 x^Catalan], -Pi < x <= Pi, -1 <= s1 <= 1, -1 <= s2 <=     1, -1 <= s3 <= 1}, {x, s1, s2, s3}, Reals] ` during a dozen minutes in 13.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: @Akku14: The same issue with `Reduce[{s1 s2 s3 == 1, s1 == Sin[Surd[x, 3]], 
  s2 == Sin[1755 *Surd[x, 3]], 
  s3 == Sin[2011* Surd[x, 3]], -Pi < x <= Pi, -1 <= s1 <= 1, -1 <= 
   s2 <= 1, -1 <= s3 <= 1}, {x, s1, s2, s3}, Reals]` on the same OS on a fresh kernel.

Comment: @user64494 `c = Catalan;
Solve[{s1 s2 s3 == 1, s1 == Sin[x^c], s2 == Sin[1755 x^c], 
  s3 == Sin[2011 x^c], -Pi < x <= Pi, -1 <= s1 <= 1, -1 <= s2 <= 
   1, -1 <= s3 <= 1}, {x, s1, s2, s3}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]`

Comment: `Solve[{(s1 - 1)^2 + (s2^2 - 1)^2 + (s3^2 - 1)^2 == 0, s1 == Sin[x], 
  s2 == Sin[1755 x], 
  s3 == Sin[2011 x], -Pi < x <= Pi, -1 <= s1 <= 1, -1 <= s2 <= 1, -1 <=
    s3 <= 1}, {x, s1, s2, s3}, Reals, Method -> Reduce]` is running without any responce for a long time. This is the same equation `Sin[x]*Sin[1755*x]*Sin[2011*x] == 1`, but in other formulas.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of problems cannot be solved using exact techniques and require numeric solution. Search this site for examples of [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) and [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html). For the example provided by user64494,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = Sin[x]*Sin[1755*x]*Sin[2011*x] == 1;
```

The approximate numeric solution is

```
soln = NSolveValues[eqn && -Pi < x <= Pi, x, Reals]

(* {1.5708} *)
```

The exact value is

```
sol = RootApproximant[soln[[1]]/Pi]*Pi

(* π/2 *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn /. x -> sol

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:** When `NSolve` fails, `FindRoot` with a good initial estimate may work.

```
eqn2 = 
  Sin[x^Catalan]*Sin[1755*x^Catalan]*Sin[2011*x^Catalan] == 1;

Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eqn2], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

```
arg2 = NArgMax[{eqn2[[1]], 1 < x < 2}, x]

(* 1.63724 *)

sol2 = FindRoot[eqn2, {x, arg2}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {x -> 1.63724137606215} *)

eqn2 /. sol2

(* True *)
```

Another example,

**EDIT 3:**

```
eqn3 = Sin[Surd[x, 3]]*Sin[1755*Surd[x, 3]]*Sin[2011*Surd[x, 3]] == 1;

eqn3a = eqn3 /. Surd[x, 3] :> y

(* Sin[y] Sin[1755 y] Sin[2011 y] == 1 *)
```

This is the same equation as `eqn`

```
sol3a = NSolve[{eqn3a, -10 <= y <= 10}, y]

(* {{y -> -4.71239}, {y -> 1.5708}, {y -> 7.85398}} *)
```

Then the solution to `eqn3` on the interval `-10 <= x <= 10` is

```
sol3 = sol3a /. (y -> z_) :> (x -> (RootApproximant[z/Pi]*Pi)^3)

(* {{x -> -((27 π^3)/8)}, {x -> π^3/8}, {x -> (125 π^3)/8}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eqn3 /. sol3

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Got it! So if I want to have a scalable code that works for different $B$ with different dimensions, I should choose numerical approaches (numerical algebraic geometry methods). Am I right?

Comment: Think of `Sin[x^Catalan]*Sin[1755*x^Catalan]*Sin[2011*x^Catalan]==1;`, where `NSolveValues` incorrectly returns `{}`.

Comment: Also think of `Sin[Surd[x, 3]]*Sin[1755*Surd[x, 3]]*Sin[2011*Surd[x, 3]] == 1;`  where `NSolveValues` is running without any response for a long time.

Comment: @user64494 - When NSolve fails use FindRoot. See edit.

Comment: Yes, `FindRoot[eqn2, {x, arg2}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]` numerically solves `eqn2 = 
  Sin[x^Catalan]*Sin[1755*x^Catalan]*Sin[2011*x^Catalan] == 1;`. However, how to identify it as a symbolic result?

Comment: @user64494 - By letting `x^Catalan -> y` in the second equation, the equation reduces to the first equation. Consequently, the exact solution is `(Pi/2)^(1/Catalan)`

Comment: The important step is done by hand. Also how about an interval `x>=-1000&&x<=1000` for `Sin[Surd[x, 3]]*Sin[1755*Surd[x, 3]]*Sin[2011*Surd[x, 3]] == 1;`?

Comment: @user64494 - see edit

Comment: Let us consider `eqn4 = Sin[x^(1/3)]*Sin[1755*x^(1/3)]*Sin[2011*x^(1/3)] == 1;`  on `x >= -1000 && x <= 1000` and so on.Then, if I am not mistaken, your approach with the change of the variable leads to an incorrect result `{{x -> -((27 \[Pi]^3)/8)}, {x -> \[Pi]^3/8}, {x -> (125 \[Pi]^3)/8}}`

Comment: @user64494 - The change of variables gives the result `{{}, {{x -> \[Pi]^3/8}}, {{x -> (125 \[Pi]^3)/8}}}` Post your questions rather than asking them in comments.

Comment: I found that the Grobner basis involves $8$-degree terms, maybe this is the reason that Mathematica cannot find the solution, due to Galois theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory